# StudentRegister.php script works in local server but doesnt work in a hosted server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I cant seem to figure out why this script is not working,basically the script below works perfectly well in my local XAMPP server it inserts details perfectly but i decided to upload it to a host server, when testing it with Postman it doesnt insert details.

Am actually getting this result "Some error occurred please try again".

Here is the image

[image]

here is the scripts this is the StudentRegister.php script

```
<?php

require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = [];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['StudentsEmail']) and isset($_POST['StudentUsername']) and isset($_POST['Password'])) {
        //operate the data further 

        $db = new DbOperations();

        $result = $db->createUser($_POST['StudentsEmail'], $_POST['StudentUsername'], $_POST['Password']);
        if ($result == 1) {
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
        } elseif ($result == 2) {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Some error occurred please try again";
        } elseif ($result == 0) {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "It seems you are already registered, please choose a different email and username";
        }
    } else {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

here is the DbOperations.php Script

```
    <?php 

    class DbOperations {

    private $con;

    function __construct() {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }

    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

    public function createUser($studemail, $studusername, $studpass) {
        if ($this->isUserExist($studemail, $studusername)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            //$password = md5($studpass);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `studentdetails` (`Id`, `StudentFullName`, `Gender`, `Age`, `NationalIdentification`, `RegistrationNumber`, `StudentsEmail`, `StudentUsername`, `Password`, `PhoneNumber`, `YearofStudy`, `Semester`, `StudentImage`) VALUES (NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,?,?,?,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);");
            //$stmt->bind_param("sss",$studemail,$studusername,$password);
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $studemail, $studusername, $studpass);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }

    public function userLogin($studusername, $studpass) {
        //$password = md5($studpass);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT Id FROM studentdetails WHERE StudentUsername = ? AND Password = ?");
        //$stmt->bind_param("ss",$studusername,$password);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $studusername, $studpass);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($studusername) {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM studentdetails WHERE StudentUsername = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $studusername);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }

    public function isUserExist($studemail, $studusername) {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT Id FROM studentdetails WHERE StudentsEmail = ? OR  StudentUsername = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $studemail, $studusername);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Any one help me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

For a script to work remotely just as it does locally:

1) Network access on the proper port (default 3306). Sometimes network administrators, firewalls, various other challenges occur and the port is simply not available. Verify your packets are succeeding in their round trip effort to request this data and return with it.

2) Permissions: MySQL users are location based. A user with permission to access a database from localhost (ie: local XAMPP server) may have the Same Name but be accessing from a different location and be denied access. It's not unusual to find a server with multiple credentials for the same named user.

"bob@localhost"/"bob@127.0.0.1"/"bob@%"/"Bob@192.168.22.7" are all technically different users and can have different access credentials resulting in different permission anywhere from the DB to individual fields.

3) Logging is your friend. Server-side and client-side logging is available which will quite often be much more direct in stating your problem (although often arcane, google is Also your friend and can translate "engineer-speak" to English). I've found myself back here on Stack after googling a freaky error message more often than I can count. And remember: No error on the server doesn't mean you're dead in the water, mysql clients can log, too, (mysqli has built-in error messaging), and often the result will tell you about the "no response" result. If there's a no-response result at the client and nothing in the server, you could be blocked by networking, for instance.